# Can someone clarify why python's does not split on the delimiter?

Tags: python, csv, export-to-csv

I have a big list with tuples:

```
data = [(
  u'378329',
  u'104',
  u'13/03/2017 12:41:29',
  u'18.19',
  u'7891008171730;CHOC GAROTO BRANCO NEGRESCO 
  125G;1;UN;5.29;5.297891021006934;CAFE MELITTA EXTRAFORTE     
  500G;1;UN;12.9;12.90'), similar entries....,
]
```

I am trying to write these entries to a csv using the following code:

```
with open('sefaz.csv', 'wb') as f:
     writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',', quotechar="'", quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
     writer.writerow(data[0])
```

This is my output:

[image: bad output]

Can anyone explain this behaviour to me? Why does it split so strange?

I want this whole string:

```
'7891008171730;CHOC GAROTO BRANCO NEGRESCO 125G;1;UN;5.29;5.297891021006934;CAFE MELITTA EXTRAFORTE     500G;1;UN;12.9;12.90'
```

to be one on row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are working too hard with all the options in `csv.reader()`. It seems the last column is a multi-line string. The `csv` library can handle it just fine as shown in my example below. If you want Excel to be able to read your file, then use the `dialect='excel'` parameter:

```
import csv

data = [(
  u'378329',
  u'104',
  u'13/03/2017 12:41:29',
  u'18.19',
  u'''7891008171730;CHOC GAROTO BRANCO NEGRESCO
  125G;1;UN;5.29;5.297891021006934;CAFE MELITTA EXTRAFORTE
  500G;1;UN;12.9;12.90'''),
]

with open('sefaz.csv', 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, dialect='excel')
    writer.writerow(data[0])

with open('sefaz.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    print(next(reader))
```

Output:

```
['378329', '104', '13/03/2017 12:41:29', '18.19', '7891008171730;CHOC GAROTO BRANCO NEGRESCO\n  125G;1;UN;5.29;5.297891021006934;CAFE MELITTA EXTRAFORTE\n  500G;1;UN;12.9;12.90']
```

When imported into Excel:

[image: Imgur]

Comment: Thanks Hai Vu! Basically the issue was that I needed use multiple quotes for that particular string

Answer (score 1):

You can use double-quote:

> Any field may be quoted (that is, enclosed within double-quote
>   characters). Some fields must be quoted, as specified in following
>   rules.

- Any field may be quoted (that is, enclosed within double-quote characters). Some fields must be quoted, as specified in following rules.

  ```
  "1997","Ford","E350"
  ```
- Fields with embedded commas or double-quote characters must be quoted.

  ```
  1997,Ford,E350,"Super, luxurious truck"
  ```

See more details from [Comma-separated values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values).